# Problema de lógica em java

Tags: java

Boa noite meus caros estou com uma dificuldade com a lógica desse programa que é um relógio:

*private void updateDisplay()*
        {

```
        if(hours.getValue()==0 && (periodo=="am" || periodo =="AM")){
              hours.setValue(hours.getValue()+1);
              periodo = "am";
        }
        else{
            if(hours.getValue()==12 && (periodo=="am" || periodo =="AM")){
                periodo="pm";
            }
            else{

            }
        }
        if(hours.getValue()==0 && (periodo=="pm" || periodo =="PM")){
                hours.setValue(hours.getValue()+1);
                periodo="pm";
        }
        else{

        }


         displayString = hours.getDisplayValue() + ":" + 
                    minutes.getDisplayValue() + " " + periodo; 
    }
```

}

Todas as funções estão perfeitas realmente é só a parte da lógica que ta complicado. E quero limitar entre 1-12 por isso quando chega no limite que é 11:59 pm ele vira 12:00 am e quando chega 11:59 am vira 12:00 pm.

Comment: Quando esse código é chamado?

Comment: toda hora para update do relógio

Comment: aqui está o método:

Comment: editei a postagem e botei o méto que é atualizado a cada minuto quando se chama o método para pular minuto